# Rails4 Application Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, models, mongoid3

i have the following function that i make use of in a lot of my models. i use MongoID for MongoDB wrapper

```
def make_slug
  self.slug = self.name.downcase.gsub(/[^a-z1-9]+/, '').chomp('')
end
```

Which is the best place to place it than copy and paste it in all my models.

Also any recommendation for a good Slug Gem for Rails4?

Comment: If you want the slug to create more user friendly routes I would recommend the gem `friendly_id`: https://github.com/norman/friendly_id

Comment: @Marcus is it compatible with MongoID ?

Comment: create one super class, define this method in it and  inherit from it, what's the problem.

Comment: @HarshaMV unfortunately not (at least not that I'm aware of). Didn't notice your update before I posted the comment

Comment: [mongoid-slug](https://github.com/digitalplaywright/mongoid-slug) appears to be actively maintained and Rails 4 compatible. Haven't used it, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you could do a mixin/module, which you include in your models where you need the functionality. Like this:

Example of the module:

```
module SlugMaker
  def make_slug
    # Do your magic here
  end
end
```

And then include it in your model:

```
class SuperAwesomeModel
  include SlugMaker

  def some_action
     make_slug
  end
end
```

Comment: where can i place this file?

Comment: I honestly don't know, but I've seen that mongoid uses modules. My guess would be in `/lib`

Answer (score 2):

All models are Inherited from ActiveRecord, you can open the eigenclass to add a singleton method there and use in all models.

The method I'll choose would be putting it under lib directory and require it in each model I need it.

Comment: i am sorry i use MongoDB with MongoID

Comment: Then I'm not even sure if Mongo wrapper actually allow you to directly include files under /lib. Totally inexperienced on Mongo XD